# Invoking RegCloseKey on a predefined registry key handle

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

Consider the case of a C++ wrapper class around raw `HKEY` handles.

The wrapper class has a constructor overload taking a `HKEY` handle as input: the constructed object takes ownership of the input raw handle.
The destructor invokes `RegCloseKey()` on the wrapped handle, stored in a `HKEY m_hKey` data member.

Now, consider the case in which a predefined handle like `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is passed to the constructor overload. The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` value is assigned to the `m_hKey` member.

The destructor calls `RegCloseKey()` on that predefined key. In my experiments the API returns 0 in this case, meaning: *success*. So, is it fine to call `RegCloseKey()` on predefined registry key handles? 
Or should a further check be implemented, like:

```
RegistryKey::~RegistryKey()
{
    if ((m_hKey != nullptr) && !IsPredefinedKey(m_hKey))
        ::RegCloseKey(m_hKey); 
}
```

Comment: May be you want to forbid to pass a predefined key into the wrapper class constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN doc for the [`RegOpenKey` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724895(v=vs.85).aspx) infers that you would only want to call `RegCloseKey` on a handle which you've programmatically created.

...*If the key is not one of the predefined registry keys, call the `RegCloseKey` function after you have finished using the handle.*

Comment: I read something similar on the MSDN doc of [`RegOpenKeyEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx). In fact, I expected a return value different than 0, from `RegCloseKey` called with predefined keys; but, in my tests, `RegCloseKey` always returned 0.

Comment: I saw that for `RegOpenKeyEx` too.  Just my $0.02, but I'd probably err on the side of caution and not try to close the handle even if it appears harmless.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find official documentation that says it is OK but I know it works.

The closest I got was [this book](https://books.google.no/books?id=36lOt-iJ6kEC&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=RegCloseKey%20predefined&source=bl&ots=1OpgT85C0c&sig=FVu2t4GHb6DgqgEIy69LU0jKfH4&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=RegCloseKey%20predefined&f=false):

> You can actually call RegCloseKey on one of the predefined root key entries.

It probably happens a lot in the wild so I cannot imagine that Microsoft would change this in the future but without official documentation it is really up to you if you want to risk it or not.

Comment: Whether or not it is safe, it is undocumented behavior. Per the [`RegCloseKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724837.aspx) documentation: "*A handle to the open key to be closed. **The handle must have been opened** by the `RegCreateKeyEx`, `RegCreateKeyTransacted`, `RegOpenKeyEx`, `RegOpenKeyTransacted`, or `RegConnectRegistry` function.*"

Comment: Then again, the documentation on [predefined keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724836.aspx) has conflicting information: *"The predefined handles are not thread safe. **Closing a predefined handle** in one thread affects any other threads that are using the handle."*

Comment: @Remy You can open the predefined handles and RegOpenKey (not Ex) can return the same handle you pass in if the subkey path is NULL.

Comment: @Anders: yes, it does, but then that goes back to Phil's answer.  If the key that is returned by `RegOpenKey()` is a predefined key, don't close it.

Comment: RegCloseKey on HKLM/HKCU has some special effect. Sorry, I can't recall it now but I definitely have RegCloseKey(HKCU) used in my practice and I don't recommend to do it without a clear goal.

Comment: [RegOverridePredefKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regoverridepredefkey) allows you to map a predefined registry key (e.g. HKCU) to the specified registry key. If you close a predefined handle, the mapping breaks. It took us a while to figure this out. I recommend that you do not close predefined handles unless you have a very specific reason.